# Logged out on resume from sleep ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, suspend, logout

I use command sudo pm-suspend to put my laptop to sleep and when I resume from sleep my session logs out and saved session is lost.
It does not happen every time but very often.

Comment: I see you haven't signed on since Sept 11/2016 but do you still have this problem?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I have the same intermittent problem with Debian and `systemctl suspend`; sometimes wakes up to the login screen.  As far as I can tell it is this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/362075

Comment: Perhaps it is this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1721428

Answer (score -1):

Try use `pm-suspend-hybrid` instead. It will prepare the system for hibernate by storing all memory content to disk and then goes into suspend. The suspended state gives the advantage that it can resume very quick and because it also prepared for hibernate the system is also able to start when the power is lost.

More info here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pm-action.8.html

Good luck!

Comment: He never said he unplugged his laptop between suspend and resume for 3 days and you could have asked him that in a comment before posting your answer.

Comment: True, but hybrid suspend most likely will solve the problem if the suspend state is lost. It seemed more useful to provide a solution instead of an inquiry to figure out the exact reason why it happens.  But I could indeed have asked.

Comment: If you edit your answer with the preamble "If suspended for a long time system could shut down in which case hybrid suspend-hibernate..." or something like that, I'll remove my downvote.... the software won't let me unless you edit the answer.